# How to warmup Symfony environment before a functional test to check execution time?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, profiling

In the functional tests of a Symfony5.2 application, I added some [profiling assertions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#accessing-the-profiler-data) to check execution time.

```php
    private static function assertTime(?Profile $profile, int $milliseconds = self::MAX_TIMES)
    {
        if (null === $profile) {
            static::markTestSkipped('To test time of this use case, please unable profiling');
        }

        /** @var TimeDataCollector $time */
        $time = $profile->getCollector('time');
        static::assertLessThan(
            $milliseconds,
            $time->getDuration(),
            sprintf(
                'Checks that execution time (%dms) is less than %dms (token %s)',
                $time->getDuration(),
                $milliseconds,
                $profile->getToken()
            )
        );
    }
```

It works fine.

But each time I launch my testsuite, the first test failed because of execution time:

```sh
symfony php ./bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 9.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.4.6 with Xdebug 2.9.5
Configuration: /home/alexandre/PhpstormProjects/bb-one/phpunit.xml.dist

Testing 
F.........................                                        26 / 26 (100%)

Time: 00:19.352, Memory: 82.50 MB

There were 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Functional\MailTest::testShowArchived
Checks that execution time (2952ms) is less than 1000ms (token b6742a)
Failed asserting that 2952.1640625 is less than 1000.
```

I know this is the first functional test, because, if I change default order, I have:

```sh
symfony php ./bin/phpunit --order-by reverse

There were 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Functional\MailTest::testShowTrash
Checks that execution time (2868ms) is less than 1000ms (token a3342a)
Failed asserting that 2868.4316425 is less than 1000.
```

- I tried to purge then **warmup** cache, before launching testsuite but it changes nothing.
- I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413501/symfony-warmup-cache-before-deploying), but it isn't a good answer.
- I tried to start the server in test mode, no change.
- I tried to create a kernel [in the bootstrap](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/bootstrap.html) to [call the console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html) and clear the test cache (it didn't help)
- I tried to create an initial test like `AAATest::testAAA(){/*..some functional test without profiling assertion ..*/}`, this solution is acceptable when we launch our full tests as you can see in the below output:

```sh
Testing 
...........................                                       27 / 27 (100%)

Time: 00:20.783, Memory: 76.50 MB

OK (27 tests, 174 assertions)
```

But when a developer is optimizing a specific use case of the site, he only launchs the corresponding test, and the time is increased by startup and the test failed.

I find a bad solution to avoid that the first one failed during the full testsuite. Now, I'm searching a solution to avoid that my test failed when I launch only one test!

Comment: When you warm up the cache you do it for the test environment? `php bin/console cache:warmup --env=test`

Comment: Yes, it is. As I am on linux env, I launch `APP_ENV=test symfony console cache:warmup`. I don't think it change anything, but I will check with your command when I come back home and reply to you. Thank you.

Comment: As I expected it, it doesn't change anything. The first functional test fails.

Comment: Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/bootstrap.html that should help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried to disable Xdebug?

Comment: @Artem : I need it for code coverage.

Comment: @nicholasnet I used it to force the cache to clear and warmup. It doesn't change. The first functional test is always slowed down.

Comment: Can you post your bootstrap.PHP

Comment: @nicholasnet it is now empty. I instanciated a kernel to call the console command that clear cache. As it didn't change anything, I removed it. (I edited my answer to explain it. You could look it in the list explaining my tries.

Answer (score 1):

We probably miss more context on the aim of your tests because I don't understand how you can collect usable results with a single run of each test to get an accurate profiling.

I think what you are looking for is of course cache warm-up as already said but you might solve your problem taking advantage of [PHP preloading and its integration with Symfony](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-configurable-php-preloading).
By tagging your services accordingly to your tests you will probably yield the necessary performance to pass your tests.

But again, give more context about your intentions profiling your code in tests. I suggest that you take other approaches to load testing.

Comment: Main objective is to detected slow pages during development. So for each functional test, we add an assertion to check that execution time is under a defined time.

Comment: And it works for all tests but the first one.

Comment: Makes sense. Have a look at codeception, it might handle warmup in a better way?

Comment: As a workaround, you might get a more reliable metric of performance by counting the requests Doctrine makes and their execution time. We implemented such a method on a python project wich automated database access monitoring while running tests to warn about potential bottlenecks.

Comment: It's already done, I catch the Doctrine DataCollector and I detect similar queries to avoid the "n+1 queries" bug. I check execution time of each query, too. I only have a problem with the first functional executed test.